# Number EditText with keyboard displayed only

Tags: android-edittext

I'm trying to create an application on which I have to input numbers directly with a virtual keyboard. The problem is that the EditText Number, which is perfect for this purpose (only inputting numbers) is hiding the whole screen.

What I want is only the keyboard on the bottom half of the screen with the EditText showing the inputted number, but, even after a few times of searching, I can't find an answer. Can you please help me? this is really important.

Answer (score 0):

First you can configure an [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable_inputType) for your [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html):

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... >
```

also write `<requestFocus />` in between `<EditText>` and `</EditText>`

What worked best for me is in **Android Manifest** for activity adding:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

I hope that helps you as well.

So you full tag will be:

```
<EditText android:inputType="number">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

It will open keypad automatically when you start your activity.